# Changing XML node values recursively with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to change "text" value of xml nodes such:

```
<set>
  <a><b:x>VALUE1</b:x></a>
  <c:y>VALUE2</c:y>
  <d><e><f/><g:z>VALUE3</g:z></e></d>
  <h>VALUE4</h>
</set>
```

XML node file that I am trying to deal is very unordered,

```
$src = file_get_contents('file.xml') ;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
array_walk($xml->xpath('//*'), function(&$node) {
    echo $node."\n" ; // how to reach inline text value?
});
echo $xml->asXML();
```

How to reach and manipulate inline values?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Change "text" values to what? Please post desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML has only SimpleXMLElement objects - representing element nodes. You can fetch other node types with Xpath, but SimpleXML can not fully represent them.

In DOM you can easily fetch the text nodes with Xpath and modify them:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<set xmlns:b="urn:b" xmlns:c="urn:c" xmlns:g="urn:g">
  <a><b:x>VALUE1</b:x></a>
  <c:y>VALUE2</c:y>
  <d><e><f/><g:z>VALUE3</g:z></e></d>
  <h>VALUE4</h>
</set>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//text()[normalize-space() != ""]') as $textNode) {
  echo $textNode->data, "\n";
  $textNode->data = strtolower($textNode->data);
}
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
VALUE4
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<set xmlns:b="urn:b" xmlns:c="urn:c" xmlns:g="urn:g">
  <a><b:x>value1</b:x></a>
  <c:y>value2</c:y>
  <d><e><f/><g:z>value3</g:z></e></d>
  <h>value4</h>
</set>
```

### The Xpath Expression

Select any text node in the document: `//text()`

Ignore whitespace nodes: `//text()[normalize-space() != ""]`

Comment: Thank you!! Working perfectly!